# Set repeat notification trigger using DateComponents

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, nsdatecomponents, unnotificationtrigger

Currently working on an App need set different type of repeat rule of notification

Like repeat everyday, workday, weekday or several days of the week.

```
var dateInfo = DateComponents()
dateInfo.hour = 7
dateInfo.minute = 0
dateInfo.weekday = 1
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: true)
```

Using this API can only add one day of the week at each time,
is there any simple way.

appreciated

Comment: There's no easy way to do this. The built in `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` is quite simple, it doesn't support things such as triggering on several days a week or the concept of workdays/weekdays. You'll manually have to set up several repeating notifications with different triggers for each day to achieve your goals.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks a lot. guess will do it manually. It really freak out especially you have one notification fire in several times a day